# What does $x_e$ usually denote in graph theory?

Tags: graph-theory, notation

I found it in a script, but it doesn't say what $x_e$ actually means. In this case, I think $x$ is supposed to be a vertex, whereas $e \in E$ is an edge of a Graph $G = (V,E)$.

I'm sure that I saw this notation in the past, but I can't remember what it was supposed to describe.

More context:

The perfect matching polytope of a bipartite graph $G = (V_1, V_2, E)$ is given by the set

$\{x \in \Bbb R^E | x_e \ge 0 \ \forall e \in E$, and $\sum_{e \in \delta(v) }x_e = 1 \ \forall v\in V\}$

Comment: This could be a 0-1 variable that is 0 if the edge $e$ is not included in a set and 1 if $e$ is included in the set.  Please provide more context.

Comment: Can you give more of the context in which you saw it?

Comment: I've seen it in a multivariable Bollobas-Riordan polynomial.  Can you give any more context?

Comment: Context added..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x_e$ appears to be a coordinate of a vector $x$ that lives in a Euclidean space of dimension the number of edges in your graph.

It is therefore not specific to graph theory. What is going on here is that a geometric object (a polytope) is being built from graph-theoretical information.

Comment: Would the downvoter mind explain their point of view?

Comment: The answer fails to discuss the whole point of this definition, which is to describe the polyhedron which is the convex hull of the set of incidence vectors of the perfect matchings on the bipartite graph.  Points in the interior of the polyhedron don't have any graph theoretic interpretation, while the extreme points are the incidence vectors of the perfect matchings and have a useful interpretation.

Comment: @BrianBorchers yet it answers the question that was asked. It is not always necessary to expand to more advanced topics when a question is so elementary. Especially if you are to miss the actual answer like you, in fact, did.

Answer (score -1):

Here $x_{e}$ is a 0-1 variable where $x_{e}=1$ if edge $e$ is in a perfect matching and $0$ if it is not in the matching.

You can solve the problem with integer linear programming.  However, since the constraint matrix happens to be totally unimodular, you only need to find an optimal basic feasible solution using the simplex method to obtain a solution.

Comment: I don't think $x_e$ is bounded to take only two values here.

Comment: The polyhedron described by the OP is certainly in $R^{n}$, but the point is to find 0-1 vectors that describe perfect matchings.